# Why is the TOMCAT Server getting automatically restarted in unix?

Tags: unix, tomcat

My application is hosted on a UNIX server. I observed that TOMCAT server is getting restarted on a particular time of week. I did not find anything in crontab. Can somebody please help me to stop this behavior (stop restarting process of TOMCAT Server) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat mainly can be stopped by 3 ways.

1. Kill the process itself with an OS command
2. Use tomcat shutdown port with {TOMCAT_DIR}/bin/shutdown.sh
3. Some internal error happens or code gets executed and Tomcat shuts itself down/ JVM is dead.

You need to track down what happens exactly at that time. Check the logs of the Tomcat + webapps, and see what which way of restart is invoked.

Also another good clue is, how Tomcat starts itself after the shutdown. If you run it as a service, that makes things a bit complicated if it's option 3, you have to take a look at the application itself, not just Tomcat.